# fontawesome5 doesn't work in the \cvsection of altacv.cls

Tags: fontawesome

I am using the [AltaCV class](https://github.com/liantze/AltaCV).

When using fontawesome5 package in the `\cvsection` command as:

`\cvsection{\faHandsHelping \ Volunteer}`

I get the below error:

> ! Package fontawesome5 Error: The requested icon HANDS-HELPING was not
>   found.
>
> For immediate help type H .  ...
>
> l.11 \cvsection{\faHandsHelping \ Volunteer}

When using outside `\cvsection` fontawesome5 works fine but not in it. Can anyone help me with what's wrong with the `\cvsection` command. Here is the code

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\protect`:

```
\cvsection{\protect\faHandsHelping \ Volunteer}
```

The problem is in `fontawesome5` that uses `\cs_new:Nn` where it should use `\cs_new_protected:Nn`.

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/14363

Answer (score 1):

The `\MakeUppercase` in the code was forcing the command `\faHandsHelping` to be in Uppercase as well. So I solved the issue by removing `\MakeUppercase`. Hence, the code becomes:

```
\newcommand{\cvsection}[2][]{%
  \bigskip%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{}{}{\marginpar{\vspace*{\dimexpr1pt-\baselineskip}\raggedright\input{#1}}}%
  {\color{heading}\LARGE\bfseries{#2}}\\[-1ex]%
  {\color{heading}\rule{\linewidth}{2pt}\par}\medskip
}
```